# Does SubSquid only store finalized blocks?

Tags: subsquid

I've been doing some work with subsquid as my blockchain indexer (https://docs.subsquid.io/), I think it only saves finalized blocks, but I haven't found anything related to that.

Does anyone know if I'm right? Does it only store finalized blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is correct. The stream of finalized blocks comes from the node itself and it's up the node to figure out and report the block status (in case of parachains, that would be communicating with validators on the relay chain, for example).

Hope this helps.

Comment: support for unfinalized blocks is in the backlog, ETA Q2. It requires live reorgs of the state by the processor, but would make the squids near real-time

Comment: Really looking forward to that! very cool